# How to draw an image with Gloss and JuicyPixels in Haskell?

Tags: haskell, graphics

I have tried to draw an image with Gloss. However, it supports only bitmaps out of the box, so I ended up also using JuicyPixels, to load other image formats. What I ended up is this:

```hs
import Data.Function
import Graphics.Gloss
import Codec.Picture
import qualified Data.ByteString.Lazy as BytesL


window :: Display
window = InWindow "Mona Lisa" (500, 500) (10, 10)

image :: FilePath -> IO (Maybe Picture)
image path = do
  img <- readImage path -- load with JuicyPixels
  pure $ case img of
    Left    _ -> Nothing
    Right img -> do
      let (w, h) = (dynamicMap imageWidth img, dynamicMap imageHeight img)
      let bitmap = convertRGBA8 img & encodeBitmap & BytesL.toStrict -- to bytes
      let format = BitmapFormat BottomToTop PxRGBA
      Just $ bitmapOfByteString w h format bitmap  False -- to Gloss bitmap

main :: IO ()
main = do
  Just img <- image "resources/mona_lisa.png"
  display window white img
```

However, this somehow messes up the RGB channels. So I get the former of
[image: What I see.]
[image: What I would like to see.]

What is the correct way to pass a bitmap from JuicyPixels to Gloss?

Comment: not sure but to me it looks like the order (RGBA <-> ABGR) might be flipped - maybe try the `PxABGR :: PixelFormat` instead? (`let format = BitmapFormat BottomToTop PxABGR`)

Comment: @Carsten Good idea, I already tried that. The result is pretty much the same, except instead of green it becomes blue.

Comment: The specific problem is that green and alpha are swapped with each other. Red and blue are both fine.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So, the easy answer is to simply use an existing library [gloss juicy](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/gloss-juicy).

However, in case you don't want additional dependencies, you can just go with this implementation (copy-pasted from the mentioned library):

```hs
-- | O(N) conversion from 'PixelRGBA8' image to gloss 'Picture', where N is the number of pixels.
fromImageRGBA8 :: Image PixelRGBA8 -> Picture
fromImageRGBA8 (Image { imageWidth = w, imageHeight = h, imageData = id }) =
  bitmapOfForeignPtr w h  (BitmapFormat TopToBottom PxRGBA) ptr True
  where (ptr, _, _) = unsafeToForeignPtr id
```